# Unable to save p-editor (rich textbox content along with image) content in SQL

Tags: sql-server, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

Below is the c# code snippet which tries to pass "Note" which is a rich-textbox(Primeng p-editor) value i.e. HTML markup along with image data as base-64 encoded string to stored procedure through a user-defined table type `[Test].[ut_InsertRequest]` but it throws an exception while executing stored procedure like `Invalid operation. The connection is closed`.

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("Notes", typeof(string))

//Notes contains data like
// <p><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ........xgf/9k=\"></p>

dt.Rows.Add(
    request.Id,
    request.Notes
);

using var conn = sqlDbConnectionService.GetIDbConnection();
var result = await conn.QueryAsync<Response>(
    "[Test].[usp_InsertRequest]",
    new
    {
        tvpRequests = dt.AsTableValuedParameter("[Test].[ut_InsertRequest]"),
        itemId = 101,
    },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure
);
```

`[Test].[ut_InsertRequest]` is a user-defined table type having `Notes NVARCHAR(Max)` column. It works fine with smaller images in sizes like 5-10 kb but throws an exception for large files.

I tested for 5kb jpeg it was working but not for even 18kb. But when I inspect browser elements it was showing content-length as 111kb or request body. Not sure why but that was the case.

Comment: Is the entire payload base64 encoded, or only the image data? If the entire payload is base64 encoded then, by definition, it only contains US-ASCII characters so saving it into an `nvarchar` data type is wasting half your storage.

Comment: You don't show us where the connection is created. Connections are `IDisposable` and should be created as and when needed (i.e.: in the same method as the stored procedure call) and be inside a `using` scope so that they are cleaned up as soon as possible and not leaking resources. Have you tried using Stored procedure calls with `ExecuteAsync` instead of `QueryAsync`?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, Updated question details along with the type of data `Notes` contains and how we create connection and use it

Comment: First of all, for the exception of your program, please check whether you have [such a phenomenon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167903/system-invalidoperationexception-invalid-operation). In addition, the Notes field should store image data, why use `NVARCHAR(Max)`? You should use `varbinary(MAX)` for storage.